# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x7d0

Tags: android, android-fragments

When I am trying to load fragment in framelayout, app crashes and shows an "resource not found exception" in log cat. I'm getting an exception when application makes an service call and try to load fragment for multiple times.

Logtrace:

```
 10-08 05:38:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(27073): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x7d0
 10-08 05:38:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(27073):   at android.content.res.Resources.getResourceName(Resources.java:3192)
 10-08 05:38:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(27073):   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:896)
 10-08 05:38:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(27073):   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
 10-08 05:38:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(27073):   at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:833)
 10-08 05:38:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(27073):   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
 10-08 05:38:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(27073):   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:452)
 10-08 05:38:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(27073):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
 10-08 05:38:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(27073):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 10-08 05:38:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(27073):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
 10-08 05:38:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(27073):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
10-08 05:38:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(27073):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-08 05:38:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(27073):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-08 05:38:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(27073):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
10-08 05:38:25.866: E/AndroidRuntime(27073):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
```

Code:

```
 final FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(context);
  frame.setId((i+1000)); // since frame layout added at runtime in loop I have added iteration value with 1000 to get unique id.
 final Fragment newFragment = new Fragment()
 mContext.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add((i +1000) ,newFragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Comment: You can't use specific id by yourself like this `frame.setId((i+1000));`.

Comment: I'm just setting random id for frame layout and adding fragment to frame layout. its working fine if UI updated with single time service call if service call goes for muliple time(if second service makes before first service finish) then app is crashing with resource not found exception.

Comment: I think firstly you should find what the id #0x7d0 refers to.Is your FrameLayout frame or newFragment or others.

Comment: @FireSun its framelayout id.

Comment: So I think when fragment want to be added to the framelayout by its id you specified,but the id doesn't exists,so crashes.why doesn't add the FrameLayout to your xml?

Comment: Exactly correct what you have said. Even i have tried with place framelayout in xml instead of runtime but while adding framelayout in loop, "R.id.frame_layout_id" is unique for all framelayout so its over lapping and even i got crash and crash log says as java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0xXXXXXXX (packagename.id/frame_layout_id) for fragment "fragmentname"{id=0xXXXXXXX}

Comment: Can you post entire codes relative to your question,with that we can find the reason easier possibly.

Comment: Sorry i shouldn't post my code in forum.

Answer (score 0):

Here the problem is not with the two different services that are running and hence you are getting crash.

Your exception is very clearly says that `ResourceNotFoundException`. It means the framelayout is not created with the given id.

So please Find my below code which may solve your problem:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER);

for(int i=0;i<size();i++){
    FrameLayout layoutMain = new FrameLayout(this);
    layoutMain.setId(Utils.generateViewId());
    layoutMain.setLayoutParams(params);

    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    Fragment newFragment = new Fragment()
    fragmentTransaction.add(layoutMain.getId(), newFragment, "HELLO");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

So, creation of Ids will be done by android only with 17 and above API Version.
workaround for lower versions is below:

```
public class Utils{
    private static final AtomicInteger sNextGeneratedId = new AtomicInteger(1);

    public static int generateViewId() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 17) {
            for (;;) {
                final int result = sNextGeneratedId.get();
                // aapt-generated IDs have the high byte nonzero; clamp to the range under that.
                int newValue = result + 1;
                if (newValue > 0x00FFFFFF) {
                    newValue = 1; // Roll over to 1, not 0.
        }
                if (sNextGeneratedId.compareAndSet(result, newValue)) {
                    return result;
                }
            }
        } else {
            return View.generateViewId();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Crash is not happening at all times while loading fragment.I am trying to load fragment in framelayout and it looks like carosuel effect. when i navigate from base fragment (where i am loading data) to some other fragment  and comes back to base fragment and still data is not coming from server and now after data comes from server and trying to load in fragment app is crashing with resource not found exception.